# Using final in method parameters in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, static, thread-safety, final

As a user newly switching to Java, I have realized that in our project and some other Java projects, `final` keyword is commonly used and after reading several tutorials and SO threads e.g. [Excessive use "final" keyword in Java](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/98691/excessive-use-final-keyword-in-java), I think there is some examples that do not require `final` keyword. So, here are the points I am confused:

***1.*** Is there any need to use `final` keyword in method parameters in classes and interfaces? Because

```
CompanyDTO findByUuid(final UUID uuid);

//or

@Override
public CompanyDTO findByUuid(final UUID uuid) {
    //...
}
```

***2.*** As far as I know, it also good for thread safety, but I need to understand the basic idea on why it is used almost every possible places in Java. Normally it is used for the variables that will not be changed. So, could you please explain the idea of common usage?

Comment: You are free to accept whatever answer you see fit, but just to be precise: that 2nd paragraph in that answer is rather misleading. The fact that Java uses stacks for method parameters isn't the reason that the `final` keyword doesn't matter. It is because the language Spec of Java **says** so. Java uses "call by value", but even if it did "call by reference", you would also use a stack for method parameters. So at least that part of the answer isn't worded correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using final modifier on method parameters doesn't make much sense
   since it adds visual clutter to the method declaration without
   buying you much. As far as you can make sure that you don't reassign
   values to those variables, you are good enough to go without final
   modifier on method parameters.
2. Method parameters lie on the stack, and it is local to that
   particular thread as far as that thread doesn't publish it to some
   other thread. Since it is not shared between the other threads, no
   thread safety issue arises here. However, if the current thread
   publishes these arguments, then you are out of luck and the use of
   final modifier doesn't give you any thread safety guarantee.

Here's one such a tasteful use of final modifier to write an immutable class which represents a point in our 2-dimensional space.

```
class Point2D {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    Point2D(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // Remainder omitted for brevity's sake !
}
```

Once this class instance is created, you can share it freely with other threads and you don't need to bother synchronizing access to it's state. So, immutable objects give you thread safety for free.

You may read JLS [§ 17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) for more details on semantics of final fields.

Comment: But the OP didn't ask about **fields** in the very first place? And note that the actual point is that java does **call by value**. Talking about the method stack does actually have NOTHING to do with that.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is there any need to use final keyword in method parameters in classes and interfaces?

None. Because the effects of using it are miniscule.

> 2. As far as I know, it also good for thread safety

Not at all. A change to a **primitive** parameter is **not** visible outside of the method body. On the other hand `final` doesn't prevent you from invoking a **method** on a reference type parameter.

In other words: if your method body does something that ends up causing a race condition between different threads, then `final` doesn't help with that at all.

The absolute **only** thing that using `final` for parameters prevents you from doing: re-assigning values to it. So, it *can* help preventing stupid mistakes. But it almost comes down to pure style. Me for example, I almost never use it, and regard it useless clutter/noise most of the time.

Comment: @Jonathan See my update.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your good explanations, voted up.

Comment: "Miniscule?" or "None whatsoever?" I thought that if you removed the `final` keyword from every formal parameter and every local variable declaration in a program,\* that the compiler still would emit exactly the same byte codes. Is that not true? [\* Note: I'm Assuming that the compiler accepted the program in the first place.]

Comment: @SolomonSlow I agree, the bytecode should be the same (for method parameters and local vars). I was merely talking about the *source code side* of things. Because even there, it just doesn't create much value.

Answer (score 0):

> **1.** Is there any need to use final keyword in method parameters in classes and interfaces?

It depends on what these methods do.
For example, if they contain lambdas, some rules apply.

See JLS [§15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2)

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in a lambda expression must either be declared final or be effectively final ([§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)), or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted.

Comment: The JLS section that you cited doesn't say "... `final`," it says "... _effectively_ `final`." That is to say, a lambda body may refer to a formal parameter or a local variable from an enclosing scope if no code modifies the variable. An older version of Java _did_ require `final` in that case, but developers complained: It made the code too verbose. The compiler can always tell whether a variable is modified or not, and if your coding style is reasonably good, then other developers who read your code can tell too without wasting too much brain power.

Comment: So you're saying that if these projects use an older version of Java, than `final` would make sense ?

Comment: I'm saying that if the compiler rejects the code because the variable is not `final`, then you're using an older version of Java. If the compiler rejects the code saying `local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final` then you won't be able to fix the problem by simply adding `final`. I don't think there were very many Java versions that required `final`. Maybe only one, in which case, it would be whatever version was the first to allow lambdas.